# Как посмотреть какой запрос долго грузит MySQL?

Tags: долгий-запрос, mysql

Как посмотреть какой запрос долго грузит MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MySQL есть такая штука, как "mysql slow query log". Включается в настройках, после чего mysql будет сам вести лог со всеми медленными запросами.

- [официальная документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).
- [как все включить, на русском](http://blog.yaxer.ru/2011/10/03/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mysql-slow-queries-log/).
- [то же, но более кратко](http://itblog.by/articles/9-kontrol-nagruzki-na-mysql-vklyuchenie-slow-query-log.html).
- [специальный скрипт percona](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html), который умеет анализировать полученный лог и показывать его в удобном для анализа виде.

Comment: @KoVadim, а что делать? Если в /etc нету файла my.cnf?

Comment: значит нужно его найти.  [здесь](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/how-do-i-identify-the-mysql-my-cnf-file-2010-03-09/) стандартные пути и способы поиска.